# Let x and {x} be sets. What is difference between x and {x}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let x and {x} be are sets. What is difference between x and {x}? Can you explain this?

Comment: $x$ may be a set or any other kind of object but $\{x\}$ is the set that contains $x$.

Comment: {x} has just one element, what about x?  How many elements might x have?

Comment: $x$ can be thought of as an element, even if it is itself a set, and $\{x\}$ is a set containing the element $x$.

Comment: You might ask if it's possible that $x=\{x\}$ but if you do you'll have opened a can of worms.

Comment: Thanks your comments. I understood.

Comment: You know all the elements of $\{x\}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for comment.

Comment: $x$ is like looking into a box, while $\{x\}$ is looking a box that contains a box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example. Say $x=\{1,2,3\}$.

$\{x\}$, or $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$, has one element. That element is $x$, or $\{1,2,3\}$.

$x$, or $\{1,2,3\}$, has three elements. Those elements are $1$, $2$, and $3$.

So the difference is that the former has one element and the latter has three. *Sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements*, so, for this example, $x$ and $\{x\}$ are not equal since they don't even have the same amount of elements.

> Are there any sets $x$ for which $x=\{x\}$? The usual axioms of set theory (called ZFC) prevent this, though there are other less common lists of axioms that allow this. (ZFC is a list of axioms about sets — basically, it lists a bunch of properties that sets have. For example, one of the axioms states that if $x$ and $y$ are sets, then there is a set containing both of them, an example being the set $\{x,y\}$.)
>
> Look up Russell's paradox to see what happens when we don't clearly list our axioms.